# How to change the list of array below with ngModel and ngModelChange angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two lists of array which are different from each other and in the top I have a dropdown which will update the list below.
I want if I click OrgItem show me orgItems if I click valueIte show the list of the valueItem
In the console log of the onOrgItemFilterChanged when I change from OrgItem to ValueItem or from VI to Org there it is working and show me the list was changed but in the UI doesn't change

Here is my dropdwon

```
<app-dropdown label="{{'general.#choose'|translate}} Array" orientation="left" labelWidth="125px" optionWidth="150px" [(ngModel)]="filterArray" [items]="arrayType" (ngModelChange)="onOrgItemFilterChanged()"></app-dropdown>
```

Here is my list with *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let valueItem of isArray() ? visibleAvailableOrgItem : visibleAvailableValueItems">
    <div class="unAssignedVIs" [ngClass]="{'active': valueItem.checked, 'unAssignedVIs': true}">
        {{valueItem.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my TS file

```
filterArray = 'ValueItem';
visibleAvailableValueItems: ValueItem[] = [];
visibleAvailableOrgItem: OrganizationItem[] = [];

arrayType: DropdownOption[] = [
    { key: 'ValueItem', value: 'ValueItem', selected: false},
    { key: 'OrgItem', value: 'OrgItem', selected: false}
];

isArray(any): void {

}

onOrgItemFilterChanged(resetSelected = true) {
    if (this.filterArray === 'OrgItem') {
        this.visibleAvailableOrgItem = this.orgItem.toArray();
    } else if (this.filterArray === 'ValueItem') {
        this.visibleAvailableValueItems = this.valueItems.filter(vis => vis.level === 7).toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chellappan This is more complex to recreate a stackblitz :(

Comment: Yeap ngModelChange it is triggering the  onOrgItemFilterChanged() and tells mme what is in the fisrt If and what is in the second depends from dropdown what is clicked

Comment: i did not understand ngModelChange inside child component how it is working?

Comment: What do you suggest me to do because dropdowns are created like components so I can use everywhere I want ?

Comment: is it possible to add app-drop down component code  with some sample data

Comment: @Chellappan Sorry I have tried but it is not working :( I only wan't if in the top is selected OrgItem the list below should show me arrays of orgItem If it is ValueItem show me the valueItems

Comment: check this documentation may be this will help https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef